# Celery memory leak unexpectedly

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery

I am using Celery on centos server for 10 months.
(there was no problems like memory, cpu io etc for 10 month.)

> - **Server environment**
>
>   - CentOS 7.3 >> 2 servers (VM)
>   - celery 4 with 8 concurrency
>   - RabbitMQ 3.6.10 / erlang R16B03-1
>   - python3 - flask
>
>     > - CELERYD_PREFETCH_MULTIFLIER // not use it. (default value)
>     > - @celery.tasks options : acks_late=False, ignore_result=True
> - **My service environment**
>
>   - service is on two servers.
>   - Generally once celery workers start to run, it takes time almost 16 hours.
>   - one message takes about 2 seconds with 8 concurrency > totally takes about 16 hours on two servers.
>   - Celery is running steadily.

**But problems..**

the day before yesterday, memory is increased rapidly at moment. (Only server A)
I don't care about it because the celery running time was too short.

finally yesterday, server memory is increased rapidly. **(Only server B)**

**server B's actual memory status (for 16 hours of service and after..)**

```
10:00 am // 10%
11:00 am // 23% , service is running. normal status
14:30 pm // 25% , memory increasing start
16:00 pm // 91%
17:30 pm // 89% , add memory on server B (VM) 
04:00 am // 90% , celery job is done. but not still released.
09:00 am // 10% , forcibly restart celery
```

**something strange**

1) I don't change my application or any config, but also servers too.

2) If my application settings is wrong, the problem should occurs on two servers at the same time. Isn't it? (But When I restart celery, memory is released... so it seems celery problem...)

It's too hard to find cause ;~(
Do you have any hints?

Answer (score 2):

This is an issue with celery 4.2 and and rabbitmq. It has been added to the [milestone of celery 4.3](https://github.com/celery/celery/milestone/20) release with [issue #4843](https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/4843).

One of the solutions until the new celery version is released, is to switch to redis. Or else downgrade the celery version to 3.1.25 which is working fine.

Comment: I use celery 4.0.1. and It runs very well almost 1 year... there were no matters. 
neverthless do you think it is issue of celery...?

Comment: It is issue with 4.1 version too. You should go through the whole issues chat

Comment: I tested to shutdown rabbitmq server during celery were processing. But I didn't find any memory increase....!! (I did do my best to set my test environment under the same condition as product environment.. T^T) 

I'll try to downgrade celery version.
Thank u so much!